# How to read a CSV on local filesystem(not hdfs) using hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

Can Apache Hive create an external table on a local linux filesystem path rather than hdfs? The documentation does not have any examples of using local filesystem but i know with hadoop-aws jar s3 can be the external fileystem. So wondering if there is another jar that can enable external tables to look at local filesystem.

Comment: Why would you want that? Why can't you simply upload the table to HDFS and create a schema in hive and then load the table?

Comment: Which tool are you using to connect to Hive ? Beeline, hue or Ambari ?

Comment: *there is another jar that can enable external tables to look at local filesystem* - Yes, that's the core Hadoop JAR, but again, it's not clear what you're trying to accomplish because Hive is meant to run on multiple machines, not the local filesystem of one

Comment: jdbc from client tool like SquirrelSQL